# PHP __constructors and getters

Tags: php

I'm new in  PHP i'm using a simple constructor to input an data on a class then retrieve it via GETTERS.

```
class Name{
    private $name;

    public function __constructor($name){
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getName(){
         return $this->name;
    }
}

$name = new Name("Josel Parayno");

echo $name->getName();
```

can someone explain me how can i echo the name using the object.

Comment: You have a typo, it’s `__construct($name);`, not `_cconstructor()`, which is why the variable is not being assigned.